# How to get string between - and ^ or after - at the end

Tags: java, regex

I have following string from which I want extract string which is there **between - and ^**. And I also want the string which is **after -** only if  its the last **-** in the given string.

```
090186-1052^0901164-1052^090180046165-585^0980046166-24064^090186a980046170-24064^00046168-36495^0901846169-46731^0d019616e-34985^8004616f-13010^186a9846167-778
```

I  have written the following code but I'm getting all the values except 778 which is comming `null` instead.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(.+?)\\^|-(.+)");
        String str = "090186-1052^0901164-1052^090180046165-585^0980046166-24064^090186a980046170-24064^00046168-36495^0901846169-46731^0d019616e-34985^8004616f-13010^186a9846167-778";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
          while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
    }
```

Comment: @Tunaki he wants also between `^` so i think `split` will be better for him

Comment: @Tunaki Okay.. Let me try that option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate regex would be

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(.+?)(?:\\^|$)");
```

This reads: `-` followed by any characters (grouped, reluctant), followed by (non-captured) either `^` or end-of-input.

This way the matched number is always in the first group.

Answer (score 3):

As shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/gE0sY6/1), the number you are after is available in the second group.

Changing your code to the below should fix the issue:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(.+?)\\^|-(.+)");
    String str = "090186-1052^0901164-1052^090180046165-585^0980046166-24064^090186a980046170-24064^00046168-36495^0901846169-46731^0d019616e-34985^8004616f-13010^186a9846167-778";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
      while (matcher.find()) {
            if(matcher.group(1) != null)
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            else if(matcher.group(2) != null)
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
```

Yields:

```
1052
1052
585
24064
24064
36495
46731
34985
13010
778
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using 2 groups:

```
-(.+?)\\^|-(.+)
 ^^^^^     ^^^^
   1        2
```

Your last match is in

```
matcher.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to split the string twice:

```
String[] splitOnDash = str.split("-");
for (int i = 1; i < splitOnDash.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(splitOnDash[i].split("\\^")[0]);
}
```

Output:

> 1052
>   1052
>   585
>   24064
>   24064
>   36495
>   46731
>   34985
>   13010
>   778

Or if you fancy streams:

```
Pattern.compile("-").splitAsStream(str)
        .skip(1)
        .map(s -> s.split("\\^")[0])
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```